# Laravel DB Join with asterisk and alias select

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join

I am trying to get following query on Laravel:

```
SELECT 
  table1.* , 
  table1.colb as aaa
FROM 
  table1 
  LEFT jOIN table2 on table2.cola = table1.colb
```

This is the Laravel DB Query code :

```
DB::table('table1')
        ->leftJoin('table2','table2.cola', '=', 'table1.colb')
        ->select('table1.* , table1.colb as aaa')
        ->get();
```

But it doesn't work and I get SQL Syntax error.
This is the SQL which Laravel is making using above code which is wrong :

```
select `table1`.* as `table1.colb` 
from `table1` 
left join `table2` on `table2`.`cola` = `table1`.`colb`
```

How can I fix this using laravel way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass multiple parameters to the `select` method for each one to get prepared correctly:

```php
DB::table('TABLE1')
        ->leftJoin('TABLE2','TABLE2.COLA', '=', 'TABLE1.COLB')
        ->select('TABLE1.*', 'TABLE1.COLB AS AAA') // <- 2 separate params here
        ->get();
```